# Return 404 (FILE_NOT_FOUND) on upload to OwnCloud with OwnCloud Android API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webdav, owncloud

I created my **OwnCloud** server with Oracle VirtualBox Debian. I want my Android application to upload image to the cloud. So i created intent to get image from the Gallery and to upload it with the OwnCloud Android library from GitHub: https://github.com/owncloud/android-library
. I followed the steps from the sample but every time when i start uploading, the result is `404` - `FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType(IMAGE_INTENT);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

            File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
            Log.d("Image file", file.getAbsolutePath() + "\t" + file.getName());

            handler = new Handler();
            Uri serverUri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.8/remote.php/webdav/");
            client = OwnCloudClientFactory.createOwnCloudClient(serverUri, this, true);
            client.setCredentials(OwnCloudCredentialsFactory.newBasicCredentials("user", "bitnami"));
            client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);

            String remotePath = FileUtils.PATH_SEPARATOR + file.getName();
            String mimeType = "image/png";

            // Get the last modification date of the file from the file system
            Long timeStampLong = file.lastModified() / 1000;
            String timeStamp = timeStampLong.toString();

            UploadRemoteFileOperation uploadOperation = new UploadRemoteFileOperation(file.getAbsolutePath(), remotePath, mimeType, timeStamp);
            uploadOperation.addDatatransferProgressListener(this);
            uploadOperation.execute(client, this, handler);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onTransferProgress(long progressRate, long totalTransferredSoFar, long totalToTransfer, String fileAbsoluteName) {
    final long percentage = (totalToTransfer > 0 ? totalTransferredSoFar * 100 / totalToTransfer : 0);
    handler.post(() -> Log.d("Progress", "progressRate " + percentage));
}

@Override
public void onRemoteOperationFinish(RemoteOperation caller, RemoteOperationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(result.getHttpCode()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of file.getAbsolutePath()? And of remotePath? Bad idea to use a function like get real path from uri. Have you checked if the file exists before trying to upload?

Comment: Yes the file is exists, because I am getting it directly from the intent. Here is the log:

`D/Image file: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170812_135058.jpg IMG_20170812_135058.jpg
D/OwnCloudClient #1: Creating OwnCloudClient
D/AppTracker: App Event: start
D/OwnCloudClient #1: REQUEST PUT /remote.php/webdav//remote.php/webdav/IMG_20170812_135058.jpg
D/Progress: progressRate 0
D/Progress: progressRate 1
....
`

Comment: No you are not getting a file name from the intent. You are messing around with a get real parh from uri function which you think delivers a file name.

Comment: Your app has the rights/permissions to read files? The file path looks ok by the way.

Comment: Yes I have 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in the manifest. So what do you recommend.

Comment: Which android version?

Comment: Try to open the file yourself with a FileInputStream for a test.

Comment: My android version is 7.1.1 and I enabled the permission in the Apps. I tested now with `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                fileInputStream.read();` and there is no problem.

Comment: So you also requested runtime permission to read files.